# jslint showing Unescaped '-' but my regex is right

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if string contains numbers, "`.`" or "`_`" or "`-`".
But jslint is showing below error:

> Lint at line 63160 character 53: Unescaped '-'

Below is my code.

```
if ( value.match( /^[0-9._-]+$/ )) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to escape the hyphen anywhere inside a character class to make sure it keeps meaning the literal hyphen after a pattern modification, but surely this looks like a good pattern.

Comment: Right or wrong, jslint probably wants you to escape it anyway.

Comment: Well the regex is correct. The code you posted also is correct. JSLint probably just doesn't look at the context around it to know that. But maybe even if it does, it's a good idea to escape it - imagine if you have a regex for `[0-]`  for literally zero and dash and then you add a literal nine but it turns into `[0-9]` which is a range. It'd be a careless mistake, which I guess is what JSLint wants to prevent

Comment: jslint need some code updation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the jslint docs and got it working!
Also there is a bug reported in jshint [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/383)

Below is the fix

```
if(value.match(/^[0-9\-]+$/i))
```

Thank you for your help.